# Unicode characters are boxes

Tags: python, unicode

Why is it that some characters show up normally, and some characters (for example, &#3676 - &#3712) show up as boxes? The website I'm using is http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode-decimal.html, and even when I try to return the characters in python, they show up as boxes.

Note: The character codes end with semicolons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some code points are not yet assigned to a character yet. Code point 3676, or U+0E5C as it's commonly written, is one of those.

As a consequence you don't have to worry about these, as they will not show up in any text.